# angular directive controlleras and link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, angularjs-digest, angularjs-controlleras

I have markup like this

```
<i class="fa-font icon-user" wd-user-profile></i>
```

to show / hide this div

```
<div id="user-profile" ng-show="vm.isVisible">
  <h3>user name</h3>
  <h3>user email</h3>
  <pre>{{vm | json:3}}</pre><!-- not updating on click -->
</div>
```

and directive code like this

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('wdUserProfile', wdUserProfile);

function wdUserProfile() {
  var ddo = {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/_shared/_userProfile.html',
    controller: UserProfileController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      elem.bind('click', scope.vm.onIconClick);
      //elem.bind('click', ctrl.onIconClick); also doesn't work
    }
  };

  return ddo;
}

function UserProfileController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.onIconClick = function() {
    vm.isVisible = !vm.isVisible;
    console.log(vm.isVisible);
  };
}
```

The problem is that although event fires and vm.isVisible changes well, in view div nothing happens. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Anything run outside angular context doesn't intimate angular digest system to run digest cycle for updating binding.

You need to kick off digest cycle manually, as you are updating scope from event(outside world). So that will update view bindings. You can use `scope.$apply()`/`$timeout` for running digest cycle.

```
elem.bind('click', function(){
    //don't forget to inject $timeout depenency.
    $timeout(scope.vm.onIconClick); //$timeout will run code in next digest
}));
```

There might be case a when two digest cycle get conflict. Simply you can not run two digest cycle at same time. What $timeout does here is that if suppose one digest cycle is running and you tried to run other digest cycle by using $timeout, it put new digest cycle in a separate queue until first gets completed and then it evaluate queued digest cycle, once all running digest cycle gets completed.

Comment: it doesn't work, all console is red (Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress)

Comment: apply() leads to errors, but $timeout version works great, thank you!

Comment: Look at my updated answer..will help you..what were happening behind the scene